# HTML5 Audio does not play more than once

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

this does not work for me! anyone having the same issue? my code seems straightforward but it only plays once I need to be able to play over and over. see as follows:

My Html:

```
<audio id="siren" src="sounds/400.ogg" preload="auto">
```

and my JS:

```
function play_siren() {
    log("play sound");
    if(document.getElementById('siren').paused == true){
        document.getElementById('siren').play();
    }
}
function pause_siren() {

    try{
        if(document.getElementById('siren').paused == false){
            document.getElementById('siren').pause();
        }
        log("paused siren");
    }catch(err){
        log(err.message);
    }
    try{
        if(document.getElementById('siren').currentTime > 0.0){
           document.getElementById('siren').currentTime = 0.0;
        }
        log("reset siren");
    }catch(err){
        log(err.message);
    }
}
```

it is started programmatically in the JS code as follows:

```
if(Obj[3].siren == true && isPlayingSiren == false){
    play_siren();
    isPlayingSiren = true;
}else if(Obj[3].siren == false && isPlayingSiren == true){
    pause_siren();
    isPlayingSiren = false;
}
```

I found this gentleman's code and his DOES seem to work: http://html5.komplett.cc/code/chap_video/js_audioPlayer_en.html

But setting "currentTime = 0" is not doing anything for me.

I can't figure it out. I tested with Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Firefox does not work at all so far Chrome seems to be the best for HTML5 but still I can only play once.

I even tried mp3 and ogg same behavior.

Please shed some light. Thank you!

here is full HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="js_audioPlayer.css">
<title>HTMLMediaElement example - Audio Player</title>
<script src="../js/audioPlayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
<audio src="sounds/400.ogg" preload="auto"></audio>
<legend>Audio Player (400)</legend>
</fieldset>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc(){ 
_pause();
updateProgress(0);
playPause();
}

var loadXmlTimer = setInterval(loadXMLDoc, 2000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is full javascript:

```
// global callback functions
var playPause, updateProgress, _play, _pause;

/* initialize audio player */
window.onload = function() {
// keep track of playback status
var AudioStatus = {
isPlaying : false
};

// define references to audio, pulldown menu, play-button, slider and time display
var audio = document.querySelector("AUDIO");

/* load track by menu-index */
var loadTrack = function(idx) {
audio.src = '../sounds/400.ogg';
audio.load();
};

/* callback to play or pause */
_play = function() {
audio.play();
log("play");
AudioStatus.isPlaying = true;
};

_pause = function() {
audio.pause();
log("pause");
AudioStatus.isPlaying = false;
};

playPause = function() {
if (audio.paused) {
  _play();
}
else {
  _pause();
}
};

/* callback to set or update playback position */
updateProgress = function(value) {

  audio.currentTime = value;
  log("updateProgress");
};

};
```

the timer plays the sounds programmatically on the expiration. this works as long it is private. I did not understand why it has to be private.

Comment: so far it looks like if I put the code inside of a private class it works but I will confirm and then post the code here.

Comment: private class seems to be stable and works well on Chrome for PC and MAC. It does not run on Android Chrome but it DOES run on Android Firefox. Looks like there is an issue with Chrome for Android or my code isn't perfect. I will debug it over USB. I just found that Chrome mobile has a USB debug feature I will try it.

Comment: alright, I see the problem but don't have the solution. If I call audio.updateProgress with any value; from the timer function loadXMLDoc it works but if I call audio.updateProgress from XMLHttpRequest context it does NOT work under this context it is READ ONLY. I don't know how to resolve threads contexts in Javascript.

Comment: still a problem with Chrome. I opened a case with Chrome developers and they are looking into it. I will update this case as soon as I hear from Google.

Comment: This flawless script might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61407319/dont-you-think-this-might-be-flawlles-solution-to-check-if-audio-is-playing

Comment: This [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61407319/dont-you-think-this-might-be-flawlles-solution-to-check-if-audio-is-playing) has some functionalities that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Does it pass thru the if statement?

You could use ontimeupdate for placing the value of document.getElementById('siren').currentTime in a variable.
If set to more than 0, then you could update it in an if conditionnal.

Answer (score 0):

All of the previous solutions are unacceptable because they download the same sound file for each time the sound is played! Do this instead, for the sake of simplicity and efficiency:

```
var sound = document.getElementById("mySound")
if(window.chrome){
  sound = sound.cloneNode()
}
sound.play()
```

This is how I fixed the problem with chrome specifically.